# Using a javascript button to go to the next array in a json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have some code that displays an array from a json object based on the id.

I'd like to write a function that allow users to click a button see the next item (id 1), then the one after (id 2), etc. What approach should I take?

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "last_name": "Dan",
    "first_name": "Terry"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "last_name": "Cal",
    "first_name": "Adam"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "year": 2015,
    "last_name": "Brooke",
    "first_name": "Lily"
  }
 ]
```

JS:

```
fetch('data.json')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    appendData(data);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });


function appendData(data) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
    var taser
    
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].id === 0) {      

      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = data[i].first_name + data[i].last_name;
      mainContainer.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="myData"></div>

<button id="btn">next</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Fetch the data using `async / await`
- add the next button event "click" listener using addEventListener() to increment and loop the `currentUser` index to get the user data from:

```html
<div id="user"></div>
<button id="next" type="button">next</button>
```

```js
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

const elUser = document.querySelector("#user");
const elNext = document.querySelector("#next");

const showUser = (user) => {
    const elDiv = elNew("div", {
        className: "item-user",
        textContent: `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}`
    });
    elUser.innerHTML = ""; // Clear existing
    elUser.append(elDiv);
};

(async() => {
    try {
        let currentUser = 0;

        const res = await fetch('data.json');
        const data = await res.json();

        showUser(data[currentUser]); // Show first one

        elNext.addEventListener("click", () => {
            currentUser += 1; // Advance
            currentUser %= data.length; // Loop-back to index 0
            showUser(data[currentUser]); // Show next
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for something like this.

```js
// fetch('data.json')
//   .then(function (response) {
//     return response.json();
//   })
//   .then(function (data) {
//     appendData(data);
//   })
//   .catch(function (err) {
//     console.log(err);
//   });
let json = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "last_name": "Dan",
    "first_name": "Terry"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "last_name": "Cal",
    "first_name": "Adam"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "year": 2015,
    "last_name": "Brooke",
    "first_name": "Lily"
  }
];
let mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
let div = document.createElement("div");
let counter = 0
div.innerText = json[0].first_name + ' ' + json[0].last_name
mainContainer.appendChild(div);
function appendData() {
  counter++;
  for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    if (json[i].id === counter) {
      div.innerText = json[i].first_name +' ' + json[i].last_name;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myData"></div>

<button onclick="appendData()" id="btn">next</button>
```

Comment: There's no need to use `mainContainer.appendChild(div);` inside the `for` loop - since you already appended that DIV. Also, what's the purpose of having a button that does nothing (once you reach the end of your users)? Also the `for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {` is completely unnecessary. Increment the counter and that's it.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. *Also the for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { is completely unnecessary* I need to iterate the object first before doing condition and it's base on the question.

Comment: Avoid unsafe, hard to debug inline `on*` attribute handlers, instead use the preferred addEventListener. PS your code has some flaws and unnecessary reuse of code. A better variant would look like: https://jsfiddle.net/ag5pfvqh/

Comment: It was understood. Again, thank you for your time and effort :)